# Maxing out on $digest iterations

Tags: angularjs

I'm playing around with directives and `=` binding in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_nth/u4BTu/2/). I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function () {\n                  var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);\n\n                  if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {\n                    // we are out of sync and need to copy\n                    if (parentValue !== lastValue) {\n                      // parent changed and it has precedence\n                      lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;\n                    } else {\n                      // if the parent can be assigned then do so\n                      parentSet(parentScope, lastValue = scope[scopeName]);\n                    }\n                  }\n                  return parentValue;\n                }; newVal: {\"baz\":3}; oldVal: {\"baz\":3}"],["fn: function () {\n                  var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);\n\n                  if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {\n                    // we are out of sync and need to copy\n                    if (parentValue !== lastValue) {\n                      // parent changed and it has precedence\n                      lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;\n                    } else {\n                      // if the parent can be assigned then do so\n                      parentSet(parentScope, lastValue = scope[scopeName]);\n                    }\n                  }\n                  return parentValue;\n                }; newVal: {\"baz\":3}; oldVal: {\"baz\":3}"],["fn: function () {\n                  var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);\n\n                  if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {\n                    // we are out of sync and need to copy\n                    if (parentValue !== lastValue) {\n                      // parent changed and it has precedence\n                      lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;\n                    } else {\n                      // if the parent can be assigned then do so\n                      parentSet(parentScope, lastValue = scope[scopeName]);\n                    }\n                  }\n                  return parentValue;\n                }; newVal: {\"baz\":3}; oldVal: {\"baz\":3}"],["fn: function () {\n                  var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);\n\n                  if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {\n                    // we are out of sync and need to copy\n                    if (parentValue !== lastValue) {\n                      // parent changed and it has precedence\n                      lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;\n                    } else {\n                      // if the parent can be assigned then do so\n                      parentSet(parentScope, lastValue = scope[scopeName]);\n                    }\n                  }\n                  return parentValue;\n                }; newVal: {\"baz\":3}; oldVal: {\"baz\":3}"],["fn: function () {\n                  var parentValue = parentGet(parentScope);\n\n                  if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {\n                    // we are out of sync and need to copy\n                    if (parentValue !== lastValue) {\n                      // parent changed and it has precedence\n                      lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;\n                    } else {\n                      // if the parent can be assigned then do so\n                      parentSet(parentScope, lastValue = scope[scopeName]);\n                    }\n                  }\n                  return parentValue;\n                }; newVal: {\"baz\":3}; oldVal: {\"baz\":3}"]] angular.js:7729
Scope.$digest angular.js:7729
Scope.$apply angular.js:7894
(anonymous function) angular.js:930
invoke angular.js:2788
bootstrap angular.js:928
angularInit angular.js:904
(anonymous function) angular.js:14397
trigger angular.js:1695
(anonymous function) angular.js:1930
forEach angular.js:110
eventHandler angular.js:1929
```

Why is this happening? I think it has something to do with the `=` binding.

Comment: Really? You don't have any errors in your console? What browser are you using?

Comment: Oops! I see it now. I will just delete my comment then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because it is is creating a brand new object every time it goes through the digest cycle. Watches are registered in this `=` databinding, and so every time it evaluates `bar="{baz: 3}"` a new object is created, and so it will be different from the previous value, trigerring another digest loop. Eventually it aborts so that it doesn't loop infinitely. See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime for a more thorough explanation.

The trick is to do the `=` databing with a reference that won't be changing every time. This is usually done by having it in the scope outside the directive. See http://jsfiddle.net/u4BTu/7/

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, but is a little painful. Is there a way to use structural equality instead of referential equality, like the boolean that can be passed to `scope.$watch()`?

Comment: `scope.$watch()` does have a third parameter that, if true, will "Compare object for equality rather than for reference." See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: Is it possible to specify that a directives '=' binding should use object equality comparison instead of reference, allowing you to define the json object in html instead of the ctrl?

Comment: This error is so annoying. What's an elegant way to solve it?

Comment: Furthermore I'm getting this even when the = binding is just binding to an object of strings.

Comment: The key is to make sure that whatever object you're doing the 2-way data binding on does not create a new reference every digest cycle. Put together a fiddle demonstrating your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve object literal expression on the HTML template:

```
<div my-directive="{ param: 34, param2: 'cool' }" another-param="parentScopeObject"></div>

var directiveFunction = function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            myDirective: '&',
            anotherParam: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){

            //this will return the actual object from the object expression!
            console.log(scope.myDirective());
            //this will return the actual object from the parent scope, if it exists of course!
            //and no "parentScopeObject" is not a function, it's an object
            console.log(scope.anotherParam());

        }
    };
}
```

This is extracted from my list of Angular binding examples. See number 6: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your application definition or app.js This will increase digestTtl for appliation.

```
yourApp.config(function ($rootScopeProvider) {
       $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(15); 
       // 15 is int value, just set to more than 10. If not works justincrement it bye one every-time and refresh page to test
  })
```