# AngularJS $watch: 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that holds tasks for my todo app. It has `getActive()` and `getCompleted()` methods that return an array with the active, and completed method respectively.

I want to show the number of compelted, active and total tasks. I was doing this with angular's `$watch`

```
$scope.active = tasks.getActive().length;
$scope.completed = tasks.getCompleted().length;

$scope.$watch(tasks.getActive, function() {
  $scope.active = tasks.getActive().length;
}); 

$scope.$watch(tasks.getCompleted, function() {
  $scope.completed = tasks.getCompleted().length;
});
```

It works fine, but it throws lot of errors to the console everytime I change a task state or I delete it.

```
Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

Comment: The best approach to this for me has been to define something like `getActiveLength()` and `getCompletedLength()` and watch those functions instead. I believe that calling the function within a watch that's watching it will recursively trigger another watch.

Comment: You may want to check out the source code of the demo app @ http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs-perf/#/

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need those watches. In AngularJS, most expressions in the view get updated on the fly, so you can use `tasks.getCompleted().length` directly, like:

```
$scope.active = function(){
    return tasks.getActive().length;
};
$scope.completed = function(){
    return tasks.getCompleted().length;
};
```

As for the 10 digests error, see [Maxing out on $digest iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594732/maxing-out-on-digest-iterations?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should call `getActive` and `getCompleted` again in your `$watch` callback, you can actually specify it as a `function(newValue, oldValue)` and have the new and old values without having to call the method again, which may result in a `$digest` loop.