# Why does $httpbackend.flush cause my $scope.$watch to fire indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

When running a Jasmine unit test for an Angular controller, it fails with the message

```
'Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!'
```

when $httpbackend.flush() is called.

This is my controller:

```
theApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, globalstate){
     $scope.currentThing = globalstate.getCurrentThing();
         $scope.success = false;

     $scope.$watch(globalstate.getCurrentThing, function(newValue, oldValue){
          $scope.currentThing = newValue;
     });

     $scope.submitStuff = function(thing){
          $http.put('/api/thing/PutThing', thing, {params: {id: thing.Id}})
          .success(function(){          
                $scope.success = true;
          })
     };
});
```

This is my unittest:

```
describe('myCtrl', function(){

    var myController = null;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('theApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        $controllerService = $injector.get('$controller');
        mockGlobalState = {
            getCurrentThing : function(){
                return {Id: 1, name: 'thing1'};
            }
        };

        $controllerService('myCtrl', {$scope: scope, globalstate: mockGlobalState});
   }));

   it('should set flag on success', function(){
       var theThing = {Id: 2, name: ""};
       $httpBackend.expectPUT('/api/thing/PutThing?id=2',JSON.stringify(theThing)).respond(200,'');

       scope.submitStuff(theThing, 0);

       $httpBackend.flush();

       expect(scope.basicupdateSucceeded).toBe(true);
   });
```

});

When I set the third parameter in $scope.$watch to true, (compare object equality instead of reference), the test passes.

Why does $httpbackend.flush() cause the $watch to trigger? 
And why does the watch trigger itself after that?

Comment: Where is `submitVenue` defined?

Comment: It was supposed to be submitStuff(). That function is defined in the controller. Thanks. Changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at this, this maybe helpful. It is not relating to your tests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594732/maxing-out-on-digest-iterations?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
// **when you are assigning something to currentThing, it will trigger watch**
$scope.currentThing = globalstate.getCurrentThing();
$scope.success = false;

$scope.$watch(globalstate.getCurrentThing, function(newValue, oldValue){
    // **here you are changing the item to whom you are watching so it can cause recursion.**
    $scope.currentThing = newValue;
});
```